# Trigger firing up in all conditions

Tags: before-trigger

Hi I am trying to induce a validation in custom object using trigger. The condition if InvoiceTotal">25000 then either second level approver field OR third level apporver field must have specht or Waterweg. If not it should throw an error before saving. Here is my code

```
trigger CT_PISA_ApproverValidations on CTPISA__BookingCapture__c (before update) 
{
    for(CTPISA__BookingCapture__c bc:trigger.old)
    {
            
            if(bc.CTPISA__InvoiceTotalVATIncluded__c >= 25000)
            {
                Boolean approver_check_ok=False;
                if(bc.Second_Level_Approver__r.LastName=='Specht'|| bc.Second_Level_Approver__r.LastName=='Waterweg')
                {
                    approver_check_ok = True;
                }
                else if(bc.Third_Level_Approver__r.LastName=='Specht'|| bc.Third_Level_Approver__r.LastName=='Waterweg')   
                {
                    approver_check_ok = True;
                }
                system.debug('Flag ' +approver_check_ok);
                if(!approver_check_ok)
                {
                    CTPISA__BookingCapture__c er= Trigger.newMap.get(bc.Id);
                    er.adderror('For Invoices bigger than € 25.000 either Waterweg or Peter Specht have to be on the list of selected approvers.');
                }
      
             }
            
     }    

 }
```

Any idea why it is throwing error in all the scenarios even if one of the field satisfies the condition?

I tried using validaiton as well but it fails to satisfy one of the conditions.

IF( OR(NOT(OR(
AND( CTPISA__InvoiceTotalVATIncluded__c >= 25000, NOT(CONTAINS( Second_Level_Approver__r.LastName , "Specht")) , NOT(CONTAINS( Second_Level_Approver__r.LastName , "Waterweg"))),
AND( CTPISA__InvoiceTotalVATIncluded__c >= 25000, NOT(CONTAINS( Third_Level_Approver__r.LastName , "Specht")) , NOT(CONTAINS( Third_Level_Approver__r.LastName , "Waterweg"))))),AND(CTPISA__InvoiceTotalVATIncluded__c >= 25000,OR(NOT(CONTAINS( Second_Level_Approver__r.LastName , "Specht")),NOT(CONTAINS( Second_Level_Approver__r.LastName , "Waterweg"))),
OR(NOT(CONTAINS( Third_Level_Approver__r.LastName , "Specht")),NOT(CONTAINS( Third_Level_Approver__r.LastName , "Waterweg"))))), true, false)

Comment: Have you set a debug on your `bc.Second_Level_Approver__r` and `bc.Third_Level_Approver__r` fields? These are relationship fields, not direct object access that the trigger is running from.

Comment: You will need to query them from the DB before checking the values, right now they are null so your boolean `approver_check_ok` is never set to `true`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're trying to make this a trigger instead of using a _Validation Rule_? A Validation Rule would be more appropriate, I'd think, and doesn't need a unit test.

Comment: Second Level Approver and Third level approver are lookup fields so just checking the name is present or not.

Comment: I couldnt achieve this using validation rule because either of the fields should have specht or waterweg if amount> 25000 so my validation rule fails if both of the fields dodesn\t have them if I put AND condition and If I put OR condition it fails to checkotherwise

Comment: @meenakshimeenu That validation rule attempt is pretty messy. I find it helps to remember that validation rules aren't meant to tell us what is valid, they're meant to tell us what is _invalid_. In pseudocode, `AND(total >= 25k, secondLevel != Specht, secondLevel != Waterweg, thirdLevel != Specht, thirdLevel != Waterweg)` ought to satisfy the conditions you have laid out. It really shouldn't need to be any more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments under the question, trigger.old will not contain any relationship values (Second_Level_Approver__**r**).

One way to get those values is to first iterate over trigger.old, add the approver Ids to a set, query the records with Ids in that set, and then use those records for your validation.

Something like this.

```
Set<Id> approverIds = new Set<Id>();

for (CTPISA__BookingCapture__c bc : trigger.old) {
  approverIds.add(bc.Second_Level_Approver__c);
  approverIds.add(bc.Third_Level_Approver__c);
}

Map<Id, Contact> approversMap = new Map<Id, Contact>(
  [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :approverIds]
);

// Do validation in this loop
for (CTPISA__BookingCapture__c bc : trigger.old) {

  // do the same for Third Level Approver ..
  Contact approver2 = approversMap.get(bc.Second_Level_Approver__c);
  if (approver2?.LastName == 'Specht' 
  // etc...
  ) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply I need which user has entered before saving the record. My doubt is will it be in the old map or new map?